# How do I prove that if $|x|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that:
If $|x|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$.

---

My thought:

Since it's a theory so I'm not able to solve it mathematically also I'm too confused about "infinity algebra". I have just memorized "infinity algebra results."

So, according to me, infinity is a very large number, therefore if any number is raised to power infinity then ultimately we'll get infinity.

---

Answer:It's a simple algebra if you'll increase power of $\vert x  \vert<1$ then it'll keep decreasing the value hence you'll get $0$ too simple.

Edit:Thanku dear teachers for helping.I know it was too simple but sometimes we get struck on silly doubts like this.

Comment: If you don't want the question voted down, then you'll need to edit your question ASAP. First, you'll need to make your question clearer. What are you trying to do here? Second, you'll need to provide some of your own thoughts and attempts in solving this problem.

Comment: sir i have no idea.It's a theory question.I'm on summer vacation means no school maths teacher.Please take back your down vote or they'll ban me.Please i'm begging you this is the only way to get solve my maths doubt.Please

Comment: please explain why its answer is 0 when |x|<1

Comment: A simpler relate question: do you know why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=0$.

Comment: I haven't voted one way or another. I plan to up-vote your question if you can get it up to standards. Read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on meta. If you edit your question we can reverse its closure, and vote it up.

Comment: What kinds of results about limits do you know? Can you do any special cases? Could you prove, say, the easiest case, $x = 0$?

Comment: @Jack sir yes sir my question is similar to that.Can you please share link of that questing.I tried to find it on Google and in search box but they're not showing required result

Comment: @RafaelNadal I really don't think anyone on this site is purposely trying to downvote you and get you blocked. Your question is pretty clear, so that's a good start. The next thing to asking a good question would be to tell us what you have tried so far. Did you for example, atleast try using a calculator? For example did you try to calculate $(0.1)^{10}, (0.1)^{20},  (0.1)^{50}$ etc? Basically, tell us what you have tried so far, and any ideas/ patterns you might have observed when trying to solve it. Next, also tell us what you know about limits. What kinds of limit rules do you know etc.

Comment: Telling us what you have tried, any ideas you have, and telling us what you already know allows us to gauge your understanding and write an answer at a suitable level. (Of course, follow the link above on how to ask a good question too)

Comment: @RafaelNadal: I do not understand your response. Again, can you prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/2)^n=0$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo i know about all properties of limits and i can solve almost all question  but i just got stuck in this question bcoz it's a theoretical because i am very confused like if i do x^n and n is infinity mean too big than how can it give 0 as result

Comment: @RafaelNadal you said "infinity is a very large number, therefore if any number is raised to infinity then we'll ultimately get infinity." This is a very false statement; for it to be true, you need to assume that the number is positive and bigger than $1$. Once again, I suggest you use a calculator to calculate powers of $0.1$. You'll see that if $n$ is very big, then $(0.1)^n$ is EXTREMELY small. I suggest that before you try proving this question, you convince yourself using a calculator why the statement should be true

Comment: Thanks sir for explaining.Sorry for wasting your time on my stupid question.Your explanation has solved all my doubts related to Infinity.Thank you sir once again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $|x|<1$ implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385709/prove-that-x1-implies-that-lim-n-to-infty-xn-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$-1<x<1$$ and you raise it to any power $n > 1 $ the value of it decreases.

Eg say$ x = 0.1 , x ^2  = 0.01, x^3 = 0.001$ or $x ^n = 0.1 ^ n = \frac{1}{10^n}$ and as $ n$ keeps getting bigger , the denominator approaches $\infty $ and the numerator approaches $0 $

Comment: Yes, you have given but an example. It still remains to be shown that in general, for all $x$ in the open interval (0,1), the sequence of powers of $x$ decreases to the limit $0$ and not to anything  else.

Comment: @mlchristians Rigorous proof is all well and good , but as the OP mentioned that he is a beginner, getting an essence to why it's true is more important, atleast according to me :-)

Comment: Yes, but you did not prove it (as the question asked). Other than counter-examples, individual examples are not proofs.

Answer (score 3):

Bernoulli's inequality is all you need.

If
$0 < x < 1$
then
$x = \dfrac1{1+a}$
where
$a = \dfrac1{x}-1
\gt 0$.

Then
$(1+a)^n \ge 1+na
\gt na
=n(\dfrac1{x}-1)$
so

$\begin{array}\\
x^n
&=\dfrac1{(1+a)^n}\\
&\lt\dfrac1{n(\dfrac1{x}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{x}{n(1-x)}\\
&\to 0
\text{ as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: That approach is already covered in the existing answers to both duplicate targets.

Comment: And some of those answers are probably mine.

Answer (score 2):

we know that $|x| < 1$, so $|x^n| < 1$ for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$. This means that the sequnece $a_n = x^n$ is bounded, its sufficient to prove that $a_n$ is convergent and then we can find the desires limit. 
Without losing generality we can suppose that $x > 0$, for $x = 0$ the statement is true, then its easy to show that:
$$x^{n+1} \le x \cdot x^n < x^n \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_{n+1} < a_n, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$
This means that $a_n$ is a monotone sequence and then $a_n$ is convergent and has limit $\ell$, and then:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = \ell = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}  = x \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n, \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \ell = x \cdot \ell, \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \ell = 0 $$
For $x < 0$, we can choose two distint subsequnce of $a_n$ for both even and odd power of $x$, then both of sequnces are convergent and prove is complete.

Answer (score 0):

For $$-1<x<1$$ you can define $$x'=\frac{1}{x}$$ if $$x\neq 0$$

Comment: please explain why its answer is 0 when |x|<1 . Note i'm still a beginner in this topic.So please explain in a easier way

Comment: If we het $$|x|<1$$ so we get $$|x'|>1$$ and so $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x'^n}=0$$